# Error 0x80004002 interface does not exist when configuring src option for audio element. (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I work in Visual Studio 2012. When i try to set src for audio element this error occurs.

```
function loadFile(event) {
    ...
    parent.message2.innerHTML = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.videosLibrary.getFileAsync(a);
    parent.player.src = URL.createObjectURL(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.videosLibrary.getFileAsync(a));
    //parent.player.play(); 
}
```

HTML element:

```
<audio id="player" controls></audio>
```

So, the file with name in var "a" realy exists, I can get it's name and type by "displayName" and "displayType". But when I'm trying to set this file to src option, I see error: "interface does not exist".

Yes, the script is starting from iframe, but audio element is situated on the main page. But this is not a problem, I can easily send any information from iframe to main page (for example, to element with id="message2").

I try to load m4a file. This player supports this format.

Comment: Are you really accessing and element from the window scope and not using getElementById? That is bad practice.

Comment: When I use "parent.document.getElementById("player").src = URL.createObjectURL(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.videosLibrary.getFileAsync(a));" situation doesn't changes. Anyway, I can send information to "message2" without getElementById("message2").